# Alt Key Changes Scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, alt, flash-cs5.5

I have an Adobe AIR 3 application. For some reason, anytime I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in the application, it swaps to the next scene (or if at the last scene, it goes to the first). I can't have this in my application, and I never programmed it in. How do I get rid of this functionality? (I'm using Flash Professional CS5.5)

Comment: have you tried KeyBoardEvent.preventDefault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. On the first scene, I had created an event listener for any key press to skip to the next scene. I realized that after pressing the spacebar and getting the same result. To fix that, I added removeEventListener() into the event function. Problem solved.